# fast vector look up c++

Tags: c++, lookup

Is there a faster way to perform a vector look-up in C++ than brute force cosine similarity?

I'm trying to find the closest vector to **v** (size 1x4) in a set of vectors **A** (size 100000x4). I'm interested in finding a faster way to do the look-up/search. Currently, I'm doing all of the cosine similarity calculations over **A** for each new **v**.

Also, by vector, I mean a mathematical vector, not `std::vector`.

One thing I've tried already involves reducing the dimension of the look-up from 4D to 1D.  To accomplish this, I first calculated the cosine of the angle between all the vectors in my search set and some reference vector.  Then, for each vector to look up, I calculate the cosine of the angle between it and the same reference vector and then do a look-up through the all the cosine of the angles (via binary search).  This seems like it should work well, but for some reason it performs worse than the brute force search.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; there's no background. Could you clarify? (To start, most people will think `std::vector`, which is not what you're talking about at all.)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you're balancing you're binary tree? Have you done any analysis on it? e.g. you could have completely left or right leaning tree. Also, there might be a danger in reducing the dimensions to a scalar, as two different vectors might map to the same place.

Comment: Also, you might be able to come up with a reasonable hash function for the 4d vector, then keep a linked list for double entries. It's possible this may be easier to deal with.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  By vector, I mean a mathematical vector.  I'm trying to find the closest vector to **v** (size 1x4) in a set of vectors **A** (size 100000x4). I'm interested in finding a faster way to do the look-up/search.  Currently, I'm doing all of the cosine similarity calculations over **A** for each new **v**.

Comment: I'd update the question with this information, making the question more clear itself.

Comment: Could you build an octree?

Comment: This is purely thinking out of my ass, but could you do a pseudoinverse A \ v or something, giving you a "closest to 1" 100000x4 vector, then multiply the columns (elements of individual vectors) together, then pick the row whose column sum is closest to 1?

Comment: I have 0 mathematical or empirical justification for that statement, BTW

Comment: This is off-topic for this site. The site is for programming-specific questions, while this is more a brainstorming algorithm topic. There is certainly overlap between the people intereted in this question, of course, but without any code to fix it's not for SO. You might try http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The keyword/tag to add would be VQ.

Comment: How often do you do the lookup from the set ? If the set is fixed, can you partition the set into different sections based on their similarity. (I am basically extending a technique used to find a point in 3d space nearest to another. There you can partition the space into cubes and easily find the cube where a point belongs to using modulo notation. Then do a brute-force on the smaller cube).